# Simple fluid sim issues, 2.91

Tags: fluid-simulation

I must be missing some basic understanding in the workflow of a fluid sim.  If I create a collision object, an flow object (inflow) and a bounding domain object, I would expect I could bake and see water in the animation.  This is not always the case.  I run thru some simple water simulations that work but sometimes when I do similar I get no fluid after baking.  What is the secret sauce I seem to miss?  If I do a Quick Fluid I get a similar Domain and Inflow object that work.  Do you see any problem with this simple fluid sim setup and why I get no fluid after I bake All and run the timeline?

Domain Object
[image]

Collision Object
[image]

Inflow Object
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inflow may be too small compared to your domain Resolution.

Also, you should always 'Apply Scale' and also ensure your normals are pointing in the correct direction after re-sizing your meshes (negative scaling can result in Normals pointing in the wrong direction).

Check normals and try making your Inflow larger and don't forget to Apply Scale. Then free and re-bake the simulation.